# UIImage from Mutablearray is not displaying

Tags: ios

```
  NSUInteger index, count = [delegate.thumbArr count];
  for (index = 0; index < count; index++) 
  {

     NSString *tPath = [[NSString alloc] init];
     tPath = [delegate.thumbArr objectAtIndex:index];
     NSURL *turl = [NSURL URLWithString:tPath];

     UIImage *_thumb =[self getImage:turl];

     // Adding images to the NSMutableArray TViews
     [TViews addObject:_thumb];

     UIImage *_thumb2 =[TViews objectAtIndex:index];
     NSLog(@"Our Image is= %@", _thumb2 );

     [thumbView.imageView setImage:_thumb2];


  }

- (UIImage*)getImage:(NSURL*)myurl
{


    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    UIImage *cachedImage = [manager imageWithURL:myurl];

    if(!cachedImage)
    {
        [manager downloadWithURL:myurl delegate:self];
    }

   else
    return cachedImage;

}

- (void)webImageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager didFinishWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
}
```

But the problem is the image is not displating when i tried to log...

`NSLog(@"Our Image is= %@", _thumb2 );` is giving me NULL... help me to fix this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a logic error in your `getImage` method:

```
- (UIImage*)getImage:(NSURL*)myurl {

    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    UIImage *cachedImage = [manager imageWithURL:myurl];

    if(!cachedImage) {
        [manager downloadWithURL:myurl delegate:self];
    }
    else {
        return cachedImage;
    }

    //execution will get here if there is no cached image; the "returned" value will be nil
}
```

If there is no cached image available, then your `getImage` call is going to return `nil`, which of course will not display correctly.

Now I don't know the exact specifics of how `SDWebImageManager` is intended to be used, but from your code it looks like it will almost certainly perform an asynchronous download of the requested image if a local copy isn't immediately available in the cache.  This means that you cannot call `getImage` and expect to immediately get back an image that you can display.

You have a couple of options for fixing this:

1. Implement that `webImageManager:didFinishWithImage:` method that you've got there to handle the image that the image-manager downloads asynchronously, and restructure your code to work with it.
2. Get rid of the `SDWebImageManager` and use a synchronous request to download the image if it is not in the cache.

Comment: means to get the images from the web for my thumbnails what i have to do ... i have to display more than 15 images from the web. can u tell me any idea .....

Comment: I want to get all my images from the web if its not in my cache .. otherwise download at maximum speed and store that into some arrays . that is the reason i used the SDWebImageManger .. can utell me any ither ideas

Comment: no referece guides are available for SDWebImageManager ... can u tell me how can i use that in my case .....

Comment: Why are you using `SDWebImageManager` if you have no documentation for it (and how could I tell you how to use it, if no documentation exists)?  I'd suggest that you 1) get rid of `SDWebImageManager`, 2) implement your own simple cache for the images that you want to download, and 3) use `NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest` to download your image when it is not in the cache.